# What is the best practice to name SSIDs of home router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have an dual band ac router. I have named the SSIDs "curry" and "curry5GHz" respectively for the 2.4GHz and 5GHz bands. All my devices have been added the password for both bands. However, I found that the devices are seldom automatically connected to the 5GHz band.

Does it help if I rename "curry5GHz" to "acurry5GHz"?

Or just because my devices always reach the 2.4GHz 1st when I m approaching home?

Or as some suggest, both SSIDs should be named the same?

Comment: Why would adding a character to the name help? There are no special semantics, except perhaps for some opt-out bs. Ask yourself this: Would your devices really benefit from using the 5 GHz network?

Comment: Just guessed if two SSIDs of the same strength appear, the mobile device would try one by one in the alphabetical order from its saved profile. I m not sure.

Comment: @chingNotCHing depending on the device, they will usually switch depending on Signal Strength. Typically, unless you are using a static device that is close to the Signal, 2.4GHz will usually be faster due to the increased range. You can also adjust the Priority list per device (if they have it)

Comment: Well, like you already guessed, they won’t appear at the same time. A device will also not switch (at all!) unless necessary to avoid interrupting connections.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SSID name has no influence on which band a device will connect to.

Older devices cannot use the 5 GHz band so they'll connect to the 2.4 GHz band. This is most likely the reason of the behavior you're experiencing.

You should configure your devices by hand by examining which SSID they see, and if they see both bands, set the password only for the 5 GHz which ensures less interference.